# Use strings instead of character classes in regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression to select parts of text like tags.

```
<([^<]*)>
```

It matches texts like these

```
< some text between tag >
```

I have used     [^<]*     to regex be optimal. But problem is that text is html and it's like :

```
 &lt; some text between tag &gt;
```

How can I write regular expression for this code (and not use ungreediness)?

Thank you

Comment: I also wrote &lt;((?:[^&]|&(?!gt;)*)&gt; But it's still slower than lazyness. I don't know why but this seems more optimize than lazyness to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it :

```
&lt;((?:[^&]*|(?:&(?!gt;)))+)&gt;
```

It's a little faster than :

```
&lt;.*?&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one may suit your needs:

```
&lt;((?:.(?!&gt;))+.)&gt;
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/W9W4IujVUjvf1bVY)

But I'm not sure it's much more efficient than using a lazyness cardinality (i.e. `.*?`).

Comment: In fact it is slower than lazyness cardinality. I wonder if there would be any faster way?

Answer (score 0):

```
/(<|&lt;)(.*)(>|&gt;)/gU
```

[Demo here](http://regex101.com/r/nC4hP8/1)

Answer (score 0):

Below regex will help you.

```
<[\s\w]+>([\s\S]+?)<[\\s\S]+>
```

Look here to [see how it works](http://regex101.com/r/iG1bN0/1).